# site won't load in Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

We are working on a site for a customer and on our in house windows 10 box the site loads in IE Edge just fine.  But it won't load for the customer and when we view it on browserstack using Edge v13, it also doesn't always load.  Sometimes it loads, sometimes nothing loads, other times parts of the page load.  When nothing loads I get a warning in the console - DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "".  I've verified that the page has the doctype tag, so I'm not sure what might be going wrong.  Here's the url to the site (currently in development).  http://rhonemusearch.hiringhook.com/contact-us/

Comment: The site also doesn't load for me in Chrome on Windows 10. It works 1 in 4 times on Firefox. Looking at the network trace I'm getting intermittent 404's. Looks like something isn't right with the server.

Comment: We found the issue.  It wasn't browser related as it originally appeared to be but one of the servers on our setup wasn't getting files synced to it.